# SQL Server: backup all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, backup

I was wondering if there was any way of making a backup of an entire SQL Server (we are using SQL Server 2008) at regular intervals to a specific location. I know we are able to backup single specific databases but for ease of use and not having to set up a backup each time I want a new database, is there a way to do this?

If there is however, I must have a way of restoring just a single database from that server backup easily as though I have backed them up individually.

The method used will just be a pure backup and not a difference so no need to worry about complications.

Comment: I think you will get a better answer on the DBA and/or serverfault sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the following script, just change the @path variable to where you want to store the databases.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'  

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Obtained from:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/

Comment: Oh yeah, asking alot but I'm not great at SQL in any form.. I'm going to need the same solution for a MySQL server, what would need to be changed for this to work?

Comment: Works like butter!

Answer (score 1):

Consider backing up hidden resource database as well

```
Use master
GO

--enable
sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
/* 0 = Disabled , 1 = Enabled */
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO


--===Resource file details
SELECT 'ResourceDB' AS 'Database Name'
    , NAME AS [Database File]
    , FILENAME AS [Database File Location] 
FROM sys.sysaltfiles 
    WHERE DBID = 32767
ORDER BY [Database File]
GO

--===Copy resource files
DECLARE @ResDataFile VARCHAR(1000), @ResLogFile VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT 
    @ResDataFile = CASE NAME WHEN  'Data' THEN FILENAME ELSE @ResDataFile END,
    @ResLogFile = CASE NAME WHEN 'Log' THEN FILENAME ELSE @ResLogFile END
FROM sys.sysaltfiles 
WHERE DBID = 32767

SELECT @ResDataFile, @ResLogFile

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)

--===Copy data file
SELECT @cmd = 'COPY /Y "' + @ResDataFile + '" "G:\SQLBackups"'
--PRINT @cmd
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

--===Copy log file
SELECT @cmd = 'COPY /Y "' + @ResLogFile + '" "G:\SQLBackups"'
--PRINT @cmd
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

GO
--Disable
sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
/* 0 = Disabled , 1 = Enabled */
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```